# How to export in json format for all databases that have a conversations table from said date to said date

Tags: mysql, json, bash

Here are the knowns:

DBEngine: MYSQL
Shell:/bin/bash
Start Date
End Date

This is what I am having issues with:
How to query all database and place their names in a array
How to query the conversations table from start date to end date
How to dump that data in json format

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash  

data_base="*"  
db_user="superfly"  
db_pass="superflypassword"  
start_date=""  
end_date=""  
wdir="/home/superfly"  

cd $wdir  
mysqldump -hlocalhost -u${db_user} -p${db_pass} $data_base conversations > ${data_base}_conversations.sql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bill Karwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46016391) was right on. I used what I could and created the following script:

```
#/bin/bash

days="8"
group_name="C4"
wdir="/home/superfly/conversations"
backup_dir="${wdir}/.backups"
db_list="database_list.txt"
table="conversations"
#--
backup_date="`date +"%m-%d-%y"`"
tarball_file="${group_name}__${backup_date}"
email1="one@gmail.com"
email2="two@gmail.com"
email3="three@gmail.com"

#-- clean up any old files that may exist
cd $backup_dir && rm -rf ${tarball_file}* ${db_list} *.json;

#-- fetch database list minus the default system database names
mysql --login-path=master --skip-column-names -e "SELECT schema_name AS DatabaseList \
    FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('mysql', 'Database', \
    'information_schema', 'performance_schema', 'sys', 'schema_name')" > $db_list

#-- fetch the last 8 days of the conversations table in json format
for database in `cat $db_list`;
do
    mysql --login-path=master -BN --database=${database} --execute="SELECT \
    JSON_OBJECT('id', id, 'sender_id', sender_id, 'recipient_id', recipient_id, \
    'timestamp', timestamp, 'content', content, 'quick_reply', quick_reply, 'type', \
    type, 'seq', seq, 'meta', meta) FROM $table WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), \
    INTERVAL ${days} day)" > ${database}.json;
done

#-- remove empty jason files - compress populated json files
find $backup_dir -size 0 -delete;
tar czf ${tarball_file}.tar.gz *.json;
rm -rf *.json $db_list;

#-- email compressed file
echo "Conversations Logs From The Last 8 days" | mutt -a ${tarball_file}.tar.gz \
    -s"Conversations Logs" -- $email1 $email2 $email3
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the database names and loop over them in a bash script like this:

```
mysql -BNe "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME='conversations'" | while read schema
do
  ...
done
```

Mysqldump doesn't output in JSON format. It outputs either a SQL script, or else CSV files with the option `--tab`.

The mysql client doesn't output JSON format either.

But you could use MySQL 5.7 JSON functions to construct a JSON document from columns:

```
mysql -BN --database=$schema --execute="SELECT 
  JSON_OBJECT('col1', col1, 'col2', col2, 'col3', col3, 'col4', col4) 
  FROM conversations WHERE date_col BETWEEN '<start-date>' AND '<end-date>'"
```

This will at least output each row as a separate JSON document. To make the entire collection one long JSON document, you'll have to manually add some JSON syntax at the beginning and end, and insert commas in between the rows.

Another option is the MySQL Shell. This is a client tool that is a relatively recent product. It's free, but it requires a separate install. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/document-store-shell-install.html for installation help.

You'd use it like this:

```
mysqlsh --sql --database=$schema --execute="show tables" --json
```

In this example, I just run `show tables` but you can run any SQL query. Read more about the MySQL Shell here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-shell.html